# Compute Harmonic function lazily

Tags: haskell

I am reading a Haskell book in which one of the exercises ask to compute the Harmonic function lazily, I've came with this solution, which I think it is lazy:

```hs
harmonic n = sum l
  where l = take n (map (1/) [1..])
```

But the answer on the book seems much more complicated:

```hs
harmonic n = sum (take n seriesValues)
  where seriesPairs = zip (cycle [1.0])  [1.0,2.0 .. ]
        seriesValues = map
                       (\pair -> (fst pair)/(snd pair))
                       seriesPairs
```

Which lead me to believe that my approach is in fact not lazy, but how so? I am handling an infinite list there.

Comment: @Andra Then there have to be something performance wise with the second implementation right?

Comment: IMO, your implementation is much better than the one in the book. Unless the book wants to showcase some feature for the sake of it, I don't understand why  it makes it so more complex. Further, many micro-changes can be applied: `cycle [x]` is more commonly written as `repeat x`. `\pair -> (fst pair)/(snd pair)` is ugly: I'd write `\pair -> fst pair/snd pair` or (better) `\(x,y) -> x/y` or `uncurry (/)`. `[1.0,2.0 ..]` is more commonly written `[1.0 ..]`.

Comment: I'd have used `zipWith (/)` instead of combining `zip` with `map`, that's what the function is there for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I mean you could benchmark it, but I don't have high hopes.  The book's phrasing just looks awkward.  It's screaming at me to do some equational refactoring

```
seriesPairs = zip (cycle [1.0]) [1.0,2.0 .. ]
seriesPairs = zip (cycle [1]) [1,2..]  -- trust type inference
seriesPairs = map (1,) [1,2..]         -- unnecessary zip of repeat list


seriesValues = map (\pair -> (fst pair)/(snd pair)) seriesPairs
seriesValues = map (\(a,b) -> a/b) seriesPairs  -- pattern matching!

seriesValues = map (\(a,b) -> a/b) (map (1,) [1,2..])
seriesValues = map ((\(a,b) -> a/b) . (1,)) [1,2..]   -- map fusion
seriesValues = map (\b -> 1/b) [1,2..]
seriesValues = map (1/) [1..]


harmonic n = sum (take n seriesValues)
harmonic n = sum (take n (map (1/) [1..]))
```

Look familiar?  I believe all these transformations are available to the optimizer so if you compile with optimizations I would expect them to perform the same.  Don't hold me to that though.  But they are the same program, denotationally speaking.  Looks to me like the author just isn't very fluent in Haskell  (especially that `(\pair -> (fst pair)/(snd pair))` line has quite a thick accent).

I wouldn't call either of these functions lazy.  In fact, if it takes an `Int` argument and a `Double` result, the only function I would call "lazy" is the constant function.

Here's something I *would* call lazy: computing an infinite list of harmonic numbers, re-using intermediate results.

```
harmonicNumbers :: [Double]
harmonicNumbers = scanl (+) 0 (map (1/) [1..])
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation.

Comment: Simplifying functional programs is a joy and obsession